# Where in $PH$ are these problems?

Tags: coding-theory, polynomial-hierarchy

1. Is 'Given two codes with alphabet in $\mathbb F_2$ with Generator matrices $G_1$ and $G_2$ do they have the same minimum distance?' in $NP$ or is it in $coNP$ (I can see it in $P^{NP}$)?

If $G_1$ is known to give minimum distance $d$ then the problem 'is the minimum distance with $G_2$ less than $d$?' is $NP$-complete.

2. Is 'Given two codes with alphabet in $\mathbb F_2$ with Generator matrices $G_1$ and $G_2$ do they have the same number of minimum distance code words?' in $PP$ (I can see it in $P^{PP}$)?

If $G_1$ is known to give $N_d$ number of minimum distance $d$ then the problem 'is the number of minimum distance codewords with $G_2$ greater than $N_d$?' is $PP$-complete.